# $compile function and replace

Tags: angularjs, directive

I had a problem with my code and by playing a little I found a solution but I have no idea why is it working. Here's the thing:

```
// recompile all audio buttons
angular.element(textAsDom).find('sound-button').each(function(key, element) {
        $compile(angular.element(element))(scope);
});
```

I got a raw html as a parameter, and inside it I'm looking for directives named "soundButton" and I compile them in order to use their attached scope functions and properties.

However, my first solution was to do it like this:

```
 // recompile all audio buttons
 angular.element(textAsDom).find('sound-button').each(function(key, element) {
     var compiledSound = $compile(angular.element(element))(scope);

     angular.element(element).replaceWith(compiledSound);
 });
```

So I first compile the soundButton and link it to the scope and I got a bound element in return. Then I replace the original element with the bound element. But then all angular dirty checking nor event handlers don't work anymore.

As for now my problem is solved, however for the sake of understanding why it didn't work, I'm asking you guys if you can shed some lights about this esoteric stuff.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're approaching this a little weird.

Why not just wire up a directive to sound-button? No need to do .find.

```
.directive("sound-button", function(){
    return {
        class: 'C',
        replace: true,
        ....
    }
});
```

Comment: This is already a directive, but the thing is that I get the rawHtml from the database, therefore I need to compile it manually.

Comment: Ok, any chance you can wire up a fiddle to demonstrate that?

Comment: If you add the replace: true (like i did in the edit) will that fix your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a fiddle for showing, but that's not the point here, I just wondered why the first solution worked while the second didn't. I've read the documentation for link but it didn't tell me why a DOM replace dissociate the events.

Also, I've tried with replace:true but to no avail.